# A condição If quebra antes de trocar o valor da variavél

Tags: javascript, if

A ideia do sistema é, quando uma das bollean for **false**, o botão de envio libera para o click. Eu comparo os src dos arquivos, e se um deles for igual a **'./img/cadeiraVermelha.png'**, a variável result é igual a false.
O código fica assim:

HTML)

```
<form>
<label id='a' class='a'>
    <img class='images' src='./img/cadeira.png'/>
    <img class='images' src='./img/cadeiraVermelha.png'/>
</label>          

<!--nessa label, a img começa com cadeiraVermelha-->
<label id='b' class='a'>
     <img class='images' src='./img/cadeiraVermelha.png'/>
      <img class='images' src='./img/cadeira.png'/>
</label>

<label id='c' class='a'>
    <img class='images' src='./img/cadeira.png'/>
    <img class='images' src='./img/cadeiraVermelha.png'/>
</label> 
<input id='bnt' type='submit' value='Enviar' disabled>
</form>
```

JS)

```
function enableBnt(){
    var label = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
    var bnt=document.getElementById('bnt');//pega o botão

    for(let i=0; i<label.length;i++){
        var cadeiras=label[i].children[0];//pega as primeiras cadeiras
        console.log(cadeiras.getAttribute('src'));

        var result = true;
        if(cadeiras.getAttribute('src')=='./img/cadeiraVermelha.png'){
            var result = false;//se 1 deles for vermelho
            break;
        }
        /*me mostra apenas a primeira cadeira true,
          mas quebra antes de altera pra false na segunda*/
        console.log(result);

        /*Era pra testar se tivesse alterado pra false, mas o valor
          não chega a trocar*/
        if(result==false){  
            bnt.disabled = false;
        }
        else{
            bnt.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    enableBnt();
});
```

Tentei tirar o break para devolver todos os resutados e trocar o valor, porém só funcionaria na última label, pq nessa situação que é a segunda label que começa com a 'cadeiraVermelha', quando chega na terceira o valor volta a ser 'true'. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Agradeço desde já.[image: Para dar uma visualização melhor da minha dúvida, o meu primeiro if quer ver se tem alguma imagem com a cadeira vermelha, se tiver, a 'var result' fica false, porém, como visto na imagem, a variável não aparece como false, o break para a condição antes de trocar a variável]

Comment: Consegui entender a lógica não. Se uma das primeiras cadeiras **não** for vermelha, libera o botão "enviar"? Ou é o contrário?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você deveria colocar o `if` que irá habilitar ou desabilitar o botão após o `for`, porque você está usando `break` para pará-lo. Assim quando a condição dentro do `for` for atendida, o laço irá parar e não chegará no segundo `if`.

Para simplificar, nem precisa de um outro `if`, basta usar o valor do próprio `result`:

```
// aqui fica o for
for(...){
  ...
}
// aqui irá desabilitar/habilitar o botão de acordo com o valor de result
bnt.disabled = result;
```

Comment: Seria assim, cada label possui duas imagens, oq eu quero analisar é a primeira imagem da label (as children[0] da label). Se todas elas forem a cadeira normal('./img/cadeira.png'), o input de submit continua desabilitado; agora se uma delas for a cadeira vermelha('./img/cadeiraVermelha.png'), eu quero que o disabled do input seja false. Ficou muito confuso?

Comment: É exatamente isso que o que coloquei na resposta faz.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi o que vc queria exatamente mas adicionei essa linha de codigo que agora compara os 2 "filhos" da label, ja que antes comparava somente o primeiro e não o segundo.

Vê se isso te ajuda amigo

```
function enableBnt(){
    var label = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
    var bnt=document.getElementById('bnt');//pega o botão

    for(let i=0; i<label.length;i++){
        for(let x=0; x<label[i].children.length;x++){
            var cadeiras=label[i].children[x];//pega as primeiras cadeiras
            console.log(cadeiras.getAttribute('src'));

            var result = true;
            if(cadeiras.getAttribute('src')=='./img/cadeiraVermelha.png'){
                var result = false;//se 1 deles for vermelho
            }
        }
        /*me mostra apenas a primeira cadeira true,
          mas quebra antes de altera pra false na segunda*/
        console.log(result);

        /*Era pra testar se tivesse alterado pra false, mas o valor
          não chega a trocar*/
        if(result==false){  
            bnt.disabled = false;
        }
        else{
            bnt.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    enableBnt();
});
```